# Populate the selectbox dynamically using chosen.js - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I can change the placeholder after page has loaded (shown below),

```
$('#dropdown1').chosen();
$('#dropdown1').attr('data-placeholder', 'Pizza , Chips');
$('#dropdown1').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

But cant seem to add some values taken from a database. I want them to bee added straight to the text box, so they look like they have already been selected. 
They should look square and grey and can be deselected if wished....???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is so simple, but took me a while, was thinking I had to do it via jquery when all it was was adding one word "Selected" in the option!

```
<select class="html-multi-chosen-select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="foo" selected>foo</option>
  <option value="bar" selected>bar</option>
  <option value="dog">dog</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/mikeys4u/99Dkm/235/